# Finding href Values Using Wildcards Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect a list of urls using Beautiful Soup and Python. I'm a new user of both and I need help figuring out how to find href values using wildcards.  The HTML code looks like

```
<table class="sortable  stats_table" id="team_index">
 <colgroup>...</colgroup>
 <thead>...</thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr class data-row="0">
          <td align="left">...</td>
          <td align="left">...</td>
          <td align="left">
                <a href="/teams/crd/2013.htm">Arizona Cardinals</a>
          </td>
          <td align="right">6</td>
     <tr class data-row="1">
          <td align="left">...</td>
          <td align="left">...</td>
          <td align="left">
                <a href="/teams/crd/2012.htm">Arizona Cardinals</a>
          </td>
          <td align="right">6</td>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

I've only included the first two rows of the html table for brevity. I would like to find all the `<a>` tags with `href="/teams/XXX/YYYY.htm"` where `XXX` is the team name and `YYYY` the year and put them all into a list of urls. Right now I am using the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
from urllib2 import urlopen     
import re

BASE_URL = "http://www.pro-football-reference.com"
teams_url = ("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/crd/")

soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen(teams_url),"lxml")

teamtable = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=="table" and tag.has_attr("id") and     
            tag["id"]=="team_index")

rows = teamtable.find_all("tr", attrs={""})

test=rows.find_all('a', {'href': lambda x : x.startswith('/teams/')})

masterlist = [BASE_URL + link.a["href"] for link in test]
```

Where the variable `teams_url` is being pulled from a previously compiled url list with member of the form `"http://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/XXX/"`. The code I've provided gives the following error due to the last line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'
soup.find_all('a', {'href': lambda x : x.startswith('/teams/')})
```

Question 1) How can I make the code collect all of the  tags in the table so I have a list like

```
masterlist = [`www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/crd/2013', 
              `www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/crd/2012',
              `www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/crd/2011'
              ...]
```

without hard coding the team abbreviation since I will be a passing this code a `teams_url' variable from the list for each team.

Question 2) There is something like 50 years (rows) in the data but I only want to pull the  tags from 2012 up to and including the year 2000. How do I do this?

Also, it may seem like there is a typo in my code since the rows are tagged `<tr class data-row="0">` in the html code, however, for some reason both the lxml and html5 parser returns the tag's attribute as `<tr class="">` and I don't know why or how to fix that, so any additional help on that would be great.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points:

This:

```
teamtable = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=="table" and tag.has_attr("id") and     
            tag["id"]=="team_index")
```

Can simply be:

```
teamtable = soup.find('table', {'id': 'team_index'})
```

The following isn't doing what you think... `attrs = {""}` creates a set of one item (an empty string) while `attrs` expects a mapping:

```
rows = teamtable.find_all("tr", attrs={""})
```

You can remove the `attrs` and make this `rows = teamtable.find_all('tr')` instead.

Then:

```
test=rows.find_all('a', {'href': lambda x : x.startswith('/teams/')})
```

Can become (useful if you want to do more complicated matching later):

```
import re
test = rows.find_all('a', href=re.compile('/teams/'))
```

Or, at least `lambda x: x and x.startswith('/teams/')` to avoid an attribute error on elements that have no href...

And then with all that working, you should be able to proceed further...

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in the attrib matching parameter of `find_all`:

```
>>> import re
>>> for possible_link in soup.find_all('a', {'href': re.compile(r'/teams/crd/\d.*')}):
...   print possible_link.text, possible_link.attrs
... 
2013 {'href': '/teams/crd/2013.htm'}
Arizona Cardinals {'href': '/teams/crd/2013.htm'}
2012 {'href': '/teams/crd/2012.htm'}
Arizona Cardinals {'href': '/teams/crd/2012.htm'}
-- SNIP --
1920 {'href': '/teams/crd/1920.htm'}
Chicago Cardinals {'href': '/teams/crd/1920.htm'}
```

In short, `.attrs` will contain the href you're looking for, and `.text` with show you the text inbetween the `<a>TEXT</a>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I intend to nest this entire process in a loop and iterate across teams. What if I wanted to leave the team directory folder generic so that on each iteration it just finds all the `<a>` tags with attribute `href="/teams/xxx/yyyy.htm"` and furthermore, only grabs years 2000-2012?

Comment: Then just change the regex.